# will an ati 5650 radeon cause issues in 12.10

Tags: unity, ati, 12.10, fglrx

Seeing so many users failing to load up unity and facing graphical issues with quantal ,should i be worried as my system has an ATI Radeon 5650 mobility card.

Ps-On another note ,how do i still keep the ppas after upgrade ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be not to use the proprietary drivers, I have an ATI Radeon 5450 and using the proprietary drivers means losing the dash/launcher and top bar.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chris ,so whats the other option as in whats the open source equivalent ?

And how do i check if right now i am using proprietary driver or not ?

Comment: Most people who have upgraded as opposed to a clean install have had to purge fglrx, to be honest unless there is a particular reason for needing to upgrade I would stick with 12.04 for a little while longer until it's sorted. You will notice a considerable drop in performance by using the open source driver.

Comment: Sad ,very sad indeed , anyways to use the new unity features in precise ?

Comment: Not as far as I know but it may be worth asking a new question. If a fix comes up in the next week or 2 I will let you know, after that I will probably re-install 12.04 myself.

Comment: do the open drivers work for you with acceptable performance? I have a AMD/Intel MUX-switchable solution and the performance of my dedicated ATI card is below rock bottom. Even scrolling of browser windwos et cetera is slow like hell.

Answer (score 1):

I've also updated to 12.10 when it came out and remained without Unity, top bar and all the stuff (plus a low resolution). Uninstalling the proprietary drivers did the job, everything worked unexpectedly smooth, but soon after boot, the laptop started heating up and continued doing it, even during idle (70 celsius in idle is a lot). Formatted everything and installed 12.04, now everything works fine with the proprietary drivers (around 49 celsius while idle, will need to clean the fan soon). Will stick with it for now.

I have an Acer Aspire 5738pzg with an ATI Mobility HD 4570.

Comment: I see.This is really sad that i am missing out on the new unity features. Staying with precise therefore